# BufferGeometry create particles z-index

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, webgl

I created two particles with a threejs BufferGeometry， I want to click on each particle shows the corresponding image.

But when I clicked on the particle the image was shown and another particle covered it.

I want to know how to get the particles out of the control of the hierarchy and keep the clicked particles always on top.

code：`

```js
var scene, camera, renderer,controls;
var points;
var shaderMaterial;

var particleCount = 2;

function init () {
      scene = new THREE.Scene();

      camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
      camera.position.x = 15;
      camera.position.y = 16;
      camera.position.z = 35;
      camera.lookAt(scene.position);

      renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

      renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 1.0);

      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

      var light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xcccccc );

      scene.add(light);

      document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

      createParticles();

      createGrid();

      render();

      document.querySelector('canvas').addEventListener( 'click', interactive, false );

  }

function createParticles () {
    var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    var positions = new Float32Array( particleCount * 3 );
    var sizes = new Float32Array( particleCount );
    var pop = new Float32Array( particleCount);

     for (var i = 0, i3 = 0; i < particleCount; i ++, i3 += 3) {
         positions[i3 + 0] = i* 10;
         positions[i3 + 1] = 0.1;
         positions[i3 + 2] = 1;

         sizes[i] = 15;
         pop[i] = 0.0;
     }

    geometry.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( positions, 3 ) );
    geometry.addAttribute( 'size', new THREE.BufferAttribute( sizes, 1 ) );
    geometry.addAttribute( 'pop', new THREE.BufferAttribute( pop, 1 ) );

    shaderMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        uniforms: {
            'u_time': {type: 'f', value: 1.0},
            'u_texture_0':   { value: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/5829050?s=256&v=4') }},
        vertexShader:   document.getElementById( 'vs' ).textContent,
        fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fs' ).textContent,
        // blending:       THREE.AdditiveBlending,
        depthTest:      false,
        transparent:    true
    });
    shaderMaterial.uniforms['u_texture_0'].value.flipY = false;

    points = new THREE.Points(geometry, shaderMaterial);

    scene.add(points);

}
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
raycaster.params.Points.threshold = 5;

var touch = new THREE.Vector2();
var intersects, INTERSECTED;
var beforeIndex;

function interactive (event) {
    touch.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    touch.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
    points.geometry.computeBoundingSphere();
    camera.updateMatrixWorld();
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3(touch.x, touch.y, 0.5 ).unproject(camera);
    raycaster.set(camera.position, vector.sub(camera.position ).normalize());
    
    raycaster.setFromCamera( touch, camera );

    intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(points);
    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
        if ( INTERSECTED != intersects[ 0 ].index ) {
            INTERSECTED = intersects[ 0 ].index;
            if (beforeIndex != INTERSECTED) {
                points.geometry.attributes.pop.array[ beforeIndex ] = 0.0;
            }
            points.geometry.attributes.pop.array[ INTERSECTED ] = 1.0;

            beforeIndex = INTERSECTED;

        }
    }

    points.geometry.attributes.size.needsUpdate = true;
    points.geometry.attributes.pop.needsUpdate = true;
}
    
function createGrid () {
    var helper = new THREE.GridHelper( 100, 20, 0x303030, 0x303030 );
    scene.add( helper );
}
 function render () {

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
  
init();
```

```css
* {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
  }
  html, body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: #000;
  }
  canvas {
      display: block;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
<script id="fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    precision highp float;
    uniform sampler2D u_texture_0;
    uniform float u_time;
    varying float u_pop;

    void main () {
    vec2 uv = gl_PointCoord.xy;
    vec4 rval = texture2D(u_texture_0,uv);

    vec2 posToCenter = (uv - vec2(.5, .5)) * 2.0;
    float distanceToCenter = length(posToCenter);
    float fadeOpacity = 1. - smoothstep(0.8, 1., distanceToCenter);
    float opacity = (1. - step(0.8, distanceToCenter)) + fadeOpacity;

    vec3 bgColor = mix(vec3(255., 255., 255.), vec3(252., 222., 184.), distanceToCenter) / 255.;

    vec4 color = vec4(mix(bgColor, rval.rgb, u_pop), 1.);
    color.a = opacity;

    gl_FragColor = color;
}
</script>
<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vs">
    attribute float size;
    attribute float pop;

    varying float u_pop;
    void main() {
        vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
        gl_PointSize = size * ( 300.0 / -mvPosition.z );
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;

        u_pop = pop;
    }
</script>
```

`

Answer (score 2):

You have misunderstanding about how 3D works, therefore, you use wrong concepts and terminology. There is no "Z-Index" in 3D. There is [Z-buffer or Depth-buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-buffering) (two names, same thing), which reflects object distance from the render's point of view (camera, virtual observer). Naturarly, the purpose of the depth-buffer with depth-testing is to prevent farest objects to be rendered in front of closest ones (this also allow to optimize, by preventing unseen pixels to be computed).

Also, the background to foreground display is not controled by any hierarchy (unless the engine deliberately implements such feature), objects are simply rendered in order they are supplied. If the Depth-testing is disabled, the latest rendered object will be displayed in front of all previously rendered ones. In 3D scene, the hierarchy is relative to transformations, not display order (unless objects are rendered in scene's hierarchy order without depth-testing).

To achieve what you want in robust way, you'll have to disable the depth-desting and manually control the order which of sprites are rendered, to ensure the one which must be in "front", is the last rendered one. This is a pretty low-level manipulation, and unless Three.JS allow you to control that (which I doubt), you'll probably have to changes your tactic, or implements your own WebGL engine.

Comment: Three can sort an array of vectors and allows for the attributes to be updated with a high-level interface.